# Why syntax error occurs when a void function is checked in IF statement

Tags: c#, c++, casting, void, conceptual

What will be the output if I write

In C++ `if(5)` will be executed without any problem but not in C# same way will it be able to run.

```
if(func()){} //in C# it doesn't runs Why how does C# treats void and how in Turbo C++

void func()
{
return;
}

if(null==null){}//runs in C#
```

**EDIT**

```
if(printf("Hi"){} //will run and enter into if statement

if(printf(""){}//will enter into else condition if found.
```

**This Question is not meant for those who are not aware of Turbo Compiler**

Comment: are you saying that `if(void)` works in Turbo C++ ?

Comment: That's an error in C++ as well. And the question isn't whether it __runs__, but whether it __compiles__. Both C++ and C# are _compiled_ languages, not _interpreted_ ones. So that question makes no sense at all. `-1` from me.

Comment: @sbi: No issues with your -1, thanks anyway. I am not considering VS C++, I specified explicitly for turbo compiler. @Henk: Yes I do mean the same but only in Turbo Compiler

Comment: @Shantanu: Sorry, but I simply don't believe that any version of TC ever allowed you to compile `if(func())` if `func()` returns `void`.

Comment: @sbi: This is allowed in Turbo compiler. This compiler was used in 1990's and I too have worked on it till 2008 and never worked on VC++ and also I have seen most of unexpected behaviour in this compiler when executing any increment operators.

Comment: @Shantanu: You might want to change the text of your question then: "When I'm working with a broken C++ compiler..."

Comment: @Shantanu: Even if you don't want to switch to **VC++**, you still can try **g++**. It is probably far less broken than your actual compiler.

Comment: @Jon: Nice Comment, i like it. @jon & @ereOn: Now I works on C# just know details about the different behaviour I asked this. Thanks to all anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C and C++ there is an implicit conversion of `int` , pointers and most other types to `bool`.

The designers of C# elected *not* to have that, for clarity.

So with

```
int i = 1;
int* P = null;

if (i && p) { } // OK in C++

if (i != 0 && p != null) { }  // OK in C++ and C#
```

Comment: This is what even i experienced while working on C, C++. that's too on Turbo Compiler. For other compiler I dont know.

Answer (score 5):

In C# the type of the condition in an `if` statement has to be implicitly convertible to `bool`. This reduces errors in various situations, and is basically a Good Thing. It prevents things like this from compiling:

```
int x = ...;
if (x = 10) // Valid in C / C++, not in C#
```

Even in C and C++, a decent compiler will warn you on the above line though, if you have a sensible level of warnings.

I'm surprised if the `void` version works in C++ though...

Comment: The type of the condition in an `if` statement has to be implicitly convertible to `bool` in C++, too.

Comment: `if (x = 10)` will generate a warning on most recent compilers btw.

Comment: @Jon,@Christian: void works in turbo compiler. After working on turbo compiler at the time of my schooling it seems to be a loosely typed language I think

Comment: @Shantanu: No, it is not a loosely typed language. It is a broken C++ compiler. It is not a separate language (C++ is C++, regardless of compiler), it's just a buggy, obsolete compiler which no one should use.

Comment: @sbi: So is it just that *any* type is implicitly convertible to bool? Or just quite a few (pointer types, integers etc)?

Comment: @Jon: `struct mine {};` isn't implicitly convertible to `bool`, which is why `if(mine())` would fail to compile. Off the top of my head I can't think of any of the built-in types in C++ that are _not_ implicitly convertible to `bool`. User-defined types are if they have an implicit conversion operator either to `bool` or any of the built-ins (all?) that are convertible to `bool`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: oops! Totally missed it. My bad ;)

Answer (score 3):

Unlike C/C++, C# conditions can only be applied to Boolean values.
Note that void function does not have return value so no condition can be applied to it.

Comment: `if(true)` is vaid and `if(someString == Strings.Empty)` is valid because your using the comparsion operators to validate some context. +1

Answer (score 3):

A void function does not return anything at all, thus its return value can not be checked with an if statement.

Even C++ wont let you do that.

Answer (score 1):

in C/C++, a nonzero integer value is the same as logical true. The reason for this is that C/C++ did not have a boolean type defined, so integers were used as boolean variables. 
Later, people found out that this kind of implicit type conversion can cause unexpected behavior when the compiler tries to find the appropriate overloaded version of the function, therefore the mistake was not repeated in C#.

To get the same behavior in C#, write `if (x!=0) { ... }`